# SpringBoot integration tests failing with java.awt.HeadlessException

Tags: java, spring-boot, awt, spring-boot-test, springjunit4classrunner

Updates after review and proposal from @Bobernac Alexandru

The question is updated with proposals, you can just use it directly ;)

I have an issue while running Springboot integration tests.

My test class

```java
public class DepenseEndpointIT extends AbstractIT {

    private DonneesTestEndpointUtil donneeTest = new DonneesTestEndpointUtil();

    @Override
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("jwt", false)
        super.setUp();

    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnVentePrevHttpStatus200() throws Exception {
        String uri = "/agregats";
        MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(uri).params(params).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)).andReturn();
        int status = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
        String responseContent = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
    }

}
```

AbstractIT looks like (I replaced for more readability package names)

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = DepenseEndpoint.class,
                properties = {"spring.cloud.config.enabled=false", "spring.cloud.zookeeper.enabled=false", "spring.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.enabled"})
@EntityScan({"si.data.analytics.ven.history.entity", "si.data.analytics.ven.history.domain"})
@WebAppConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"si.data.analytics.ven"})
public abstract class AbstractIT {

    protected MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    protected void setUp() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }
}
```

When I run my tests, I have the following error, the exception is thrown, while doing `mvn.perform(...)`

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.awt.HeadlessException
>
> at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1013)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:71)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)     at
>   org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:182)
>     at
>   com.snef.si.data.analytics.ven.integration.DepenseEndpointIT.shouldReturnVentePrevHttpStatus200(DepenseEndpointIT.java:50)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)   at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.awt.HeadlessException

In my main(), I have modified the way I run my application, I set `headless` to false to avoid the error, and it's working fine, but my integration test is not working:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"si.data.analytics.ven", "si.data.analytics.foundation.logging.aspect"})
@EnableAsync
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Main.class);
        builder.headless(false).run(args);
    }
}
```

Is there something that I have missed ? Is there any way we can pass the same paramteter, i.e: `builder.headless(false)` to test classes ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to overcome the issue, by setting `java.awt.headless`
 to `false`

```java
@Override
@Before
public void setUp() {
    System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
    super.setUp();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You added @RunWith in both classes. Remove `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` from `DepenseEndpointIT` and add it to `AbstractIT` as `SpringRunner` extends `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`. Should work.

Comment: I tried your solution, but I still have the same error